# centered time window in apache flink

Tags: apache-flink

Is it possible to collect windows whose center is a particular event of interest?

Imagine a stream of events:

```
....e...........e...E........e......
```

In particular I'm interested in a trigger event E and its surroundings (+- a few minutes):

```
....e..........|e...E....|....e......
```

Answer (score 1):

Implementing this logic with Flink's window operators (incl. custom `Trigger` and `Evictor` implementations) should be possible but quite challenging in my opinion.

I think a better approach would be a `ProcessFunction`. A `ProcessFunction` can register timers (processing time or event time) that call a callback function. For the given use case, a `ProcessFunction` would collect all records in managed state. When a trigger event is received, a timer is registered to wait for more events to arrive until the window boundary around the trigger event expired. Moreover, the `ProcessFunction` needs to periodically remove all elements that arrived too early to be associated with a trigger event. This can also be done by registering a timer.

Comment: Thx Fabian for answering my question. I will check out the approach you provided.